# useEffect still trigger comparing the same object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

my data is an object with 2 property, `{a: 1, b:2}`, but I can see rerender still although my prop (data) remain as `{a: 1, b:2}`, does useEffect can't compare object?

```
const MyComp = ({ data }) => {

useEffect(() => {
console.log('test')
}, [data])

return <div>something</div>
}
```

Comment: How are you passing data as prop and where is it defined

Comment: You should provide more details, make sure you have not any console error and exported your component properly

Answer (score 1):

Even though data looks the same, {a: 1, b:2}, it can be a different object.

Consider this example:

```
let data1 = {a:1, b:2}
let data2 = {a:1, b:2}
data1 == data2 // false!
```

But here, it's true:

```
let data1 = {a:1, b:2}
let data2 = data1
data1 == data2 // true!
```

Just because the keys are the same doesn't mean it's the same object. React compares the object, not the keys inside the object.

Comment: That applies for state (in class components) and props. Pretty sure it doesn't apply for dependency arrays.

Comment: @GuyIncognito now I got you, you are right, the default part is true, seems like react doesn't use shallow compare by default. I just deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is already explained by @Viktor.

**Problem**

React will do a comparison between each of the values (via `Object.is`) to determine whether your effect callback should be called.

The problem is that if you need to provide an object for one of those dependencies and that object is new every render, then even if none of the properties changed, your effect will get called anyway.

**Solution**

1)Implement your own deep comparing algorithm. For this you can get previous value using `custom usePrevious hook` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) and deep compare with your current value.

2)Or,You can simply use https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect (It's react's useEffect hook, except using deep comparison on the inputs, not reference equality)